# 'Large' 'If' Formula Help

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am looking for a formula I can put into Google Sheets that finds the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd largest values in column B, but only for rows that also contain the number 1 in column A. Problem is, column A does have some blank cells, which I can not fill in.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | $1,000 |
| **2** |  | $2,000 |
| **3** | 1 | $3,000 |
| **4** | 1 | $4,000 |

Answer (score 0):

- Use `FILTER` to capture only the values in Column B that have an associated number in Column A.
- Use `LARGE` with the filtered data to get the 1st, 2nd and 3rd biggest numbers

e.g.: This formula in cell E2
`=Large(filter($B$2:$B$5,$A$2:$A$5<>""),D2)` where cell D2 contains a value of 1

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a query and get all 3 results directly with:

```
=ifna(query(A2:B,"select B where A = 1 order by B desc limit 3"))
```

[image: query]

Answer (score 0):

## SORTN

The [SORTN function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en)  returns the first `n` items in a data set after performing a sort.
`SORTN(range, [n], [display_ties_mode], [sort_column1, is_ascending1], ...)`

##### SORTN Formula with FILTER

[SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) is applied to the array returned by a [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function.

```
=SORTN(FILTER(B:B,A:A=1),3,,1,0)
```

[image]

##### Nested SORTN Formula

[SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) is applied to an array returned by a nested [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) function.

```
=SORTN(SORTN(B:B,1,1,A:A,-1),3,,1,0)
```

[image]